# Tab panel problem

Tags: javascript

How can I get selected tab index of tab panel using JavaScript and then assign a button validation group according to selected tab index?

This is my code so far:

```
function ActiveTab()
{
    var a= $find("tcEmployee").get_activeTabIndex();
    var add=document.setElementById('<%=btnAddRecord.ClientID%>');
    var update=document.getElementById('<%= btnUpdateRecord.ClientID%>');
    var delet  document.getElementById('<%= btnDeleteRecord.ClientID%>');
    if (a == 0)
    {
        add.ValidationGroup = "Insertion";
        update.ValidationGroup = "Insertion";
        delet.ValidationGroup = "Insertion";
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        add.ValidationGroup = "Insertion1";
        update.ValidationGroup = "Insertion1";
        delet.ValidationGroup = "Insertion1";
    }
    else
    {
        add.ValidationGroup = "Insertion2";
        update.ValidationGroup = "Insertion2";
        delet.ValidationGroup = "Insertion2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a click event on the tab?

Maybe look at the jQueryUI tab control and get the event that way.

Also, try including more information in your question so we can actually target our answers to an actual problem

**edit**

OK, looking at your code i think jQuery is going to be your friend.

if you give each of your controls an ID like you are doing and also a class.  So for the "add" alement you may give it a class of "ADD" and for"update" a  class of "UPDATE".

Then you can use jQuery like this;

```
$(".UPDATE").click(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr("id") );
})
$(".ADD").click(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr("id") );
})
```

etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Jquery tab](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Comment: i dont  have idea of jquery i m new in development